# Minimal assembly program ARM

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu, arm64

I am learning assembly, but I'm having trouble understanding how a program is executed by a CPU when using gnu/linux on arm. I will elaborate.

```
Problem:
    I want my program to return 5 as it's exit status.
```

Assembly for this is:

```
.text
.align 2
.global main
.type main, %function
main:
    mov w0, 5 //move 5 to register w0
    ret       //return
```

I then assemble it with:

```
as prog.s -o prog.o
```

Everything ok up to here. I understand I then have to link my object file to the C library in order to add additional code that will make my program run. I then link with(paths are omitted for clarity):

```
ld crti.o crtn.o crt1.o libc.so prog.o ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -o prog
```

After this, things work as expected:

```
./prog; echo $?
5
```

My problem is that I can't figure out what the C standard library is actually doing here. I more or less understand crti/n/1 are adding entry code to my program (eg the .init and .start sections), but no clue what's libc purpose.

I am interested at what would be a minimal assembly implementation of "returning 5 as exit status"

Most resources on the web focus on the instructions and program flow once you are in main. I am really interested at what are all the steps that go on once I execute with ./. I am now going through computer architecture textbooks, but I hope I can get a little help here.

Comment: The operating system has no idea about `main`, its arguments or its return value (or about functions in general for that matter). It only understands addresses and system calls. You need a syscall to exit a program! Without libc, you would have to execute a syscall manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language starts at main() but for C to work you in general need at least a minimal bootstrap. For example before main can be called from the C bootstrap

```
1) stack/stackpointer
2) .data initialized
3) .bss initalized
4) argc/argv prepared
```

And then there is C library which there are many/countless C libraries and each have their own designs and requirements to be satisfied before main is called.  The C library makes system calls into the system so this starts to become system (operating system, Linux, Windows, etc) dependent, depending on the design of the C library that may be a thin shim or heavily integrated or somewhere in between.

Likewise for example assuming that the operating system is taking the "binary" (binary formats supported by the operating system and rules for that format are defined by the operating system and the toolchain must conform likewise the C library (even though you see the same brand name sometimes assume toolchain and C library are separate entities, one designed to work with the other)) from a non volatile media like a hard drive or ssd and copying the relevant parts into memory (some percentage of the popular, supported, binary file formats, are there for debug or file format and not actually code or data that is used for execution).
So this leaves a system level design option of does the binary file format indicate .data, .bss, .text, etc (note that .data, .bss, .text are not standards just convention most people know what that means even if a particular toolchain did not choose to use those names for sections or even the term sections).

If so the operating systems loader that takes the program and loads it into memory can choose to put .data in the right place and zero .bss for you so that the bootstrap does not have to.  In a bare-metal situation the bootstrap would normally handle the read/write items because it is not loaded from media by some other software it is often simply in the address space of the processor on a rom of some flavor.

Likewise argv/argc could be handled by the operating systems tool that loads the binary as it had to parse out the location of the binary from the command line assuming the operating system has/uses a command line interface.  But it could as easily simply pass the command line to the bootstrap and the bootstrap has to do it, these are system level design choices that have little to do with C but everything to do with what happens before main is called.

The memory space rules are defined by the operating system and between the operating system and the C library which often contains the bootstrap due to its intimate nature but I guess the C library and bootstrap could be separate.  So linking plays a role as well, does this operating system support protection is it just read/write memory and you just need to spam it in there or are there separate regions for read/only (.text, .rodata, etc) and read/write (.data, .bss, etc).  Someone needs to handle that, linker script and bootstrap often have a very intimate relationship and the linker script solution is specific to a toolchain not assumed to be portable, why would it, so while there are other solutions the common solution is that there is a C library with a bootstrap and linker solution that are heavily tied to the operating system and target processor.

And then you can talk about what happens after main().   I am happy to see you are using ARM not x86 to learn first, although aarch64 is a nightmare for a first one, not the instruction set just the execution levels and all the protections, you can go a long long way with this approach but there are some things and some instructions you cannot touch without going bare metal.  (assuming you are using a pi there is a very good bare-metal forum with a lot of good resources).

The gnu tools are such that binutils and gcc are separate but intimately related projects.  gcc knows where things are relative to itself so assuming you combined gcc with binutils and glibc (or you just use the toolchain you found), gcc knows relative to where it executed to find these other items and what items to pass when it calls the linker (gcc is to some extent just a shell that calls a preprocessor a compiler the assembler then linker if not instructed not to do these things).  But the gnu binutils linker does not.  While as distasteful as it feels to use, it is easier just to

```
gcc test.o -o test
```

rather than figure out for that machine that day what all you need on the ld command line and what paths and depending on design the order on the command line of the arguments.

Note you can probably get away with this as a minimum

```
.global main
.type main, %function
main:
    mov w0, 5 //move 5 to register w0
    ret       //return
```

or see what gcc generates

```
unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    return 5;
}

    .arch armv8-a
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .p2align 4,,11
    .global fun
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    mov w0, 5
    ret
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.0"
```

I am used to seeing more fluff in there:

```
    .arch armv5t
    .fpu softvfp
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 2
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    mov r0, #5
    bx  lr
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

Either way, you can look up each of the assembly language items and decide if you really need them or not, depends in part on if you feel the need to use a debugger or binutils tools to tear apart the binary (do you really need to know the size of fun for example in order to learn assembly language?)

If you wish to control all of the code and not link with a C library you are more than welcome to you need to know the memory space rules for the operating system and create a linker script (the default one may in part be tied to the C library and is no doubt overly complicated and not something you would want to use as a starting point).  In this case being two instructions in main you simply need the one address space valid for the binary, however the operating system enters (ideally using the ENTRY(label), which could be main if you want but often is not _start is often found in linker scripts but is not a rule either, you choose.  And as pointed out in comments you would need to make the system call to exit the program. System calls are specific to the operating system and possibly version and not specific to a target (ARM), so you would need to use the right one in the right way, very doable, your whole project linker script and assembly language could be maybe a couple dozen lines of code total.  We are not here to google those for you so you would be on your own for that.

Part of your problem here is you are searching for compiler solutions when the compiler in general has absolutely nothing to do with any of this.  A compiler takes one language turns it into another language.  An assembler same deal but one is simple and the other usually machine code, bits.  (some compilers output bits not text as well).  It is equivalent to looking up the users manual for a table saw to figure out how to build a house.  The table saw is just a tool, one of the tools you need, but just a generic tool.  The compiler, specific gnu's gcc, is generic it does not even know what main() is.  Gnu follows the Unix way so it has a separate binutils and C library, separate developments, and you do not have to combine them if you do not want to, you can use them separately.  And then there is the operating system so half your question is buried in operating system details, the other half in a particular C library or other solution to connect main() to the operating system.

Being open source you can go look at the bootstrap for glibc and others and see what they do.  Understanding this type of open source project the code is nearly unreadable, much easier to disassemble sometimes, YMMV.

You can search for the Linux system calls for arm aarch64 and find the one for exit, you can likely see that the open source C libraries or bootstrap solutions you find that are buried under what you are using today, will call exit but if not then there is some other call they need to make to return back to the operating system. It is unlikely it is a simple ret with a register that holds a return value, but technically that is how someone could choose to do it for their operating system.

I think you will find for Linux on arm that Linux is going to parse the command line and pass argc/argv in registers, so you can simply use them.  And likely going to prep .data and .bss so long as you build the binary correctly (you link it correctly).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for taking the time for such detailed answer. I'll be honest, I understand maybe 10% of it, but now I am aware of many more things that I don't know so now I can start googling them. It seems I am lacking a thorough understanding of how my OS(gnu/linux) executes a binary, which is now my starting point. Nevertheless I will mark the answer as "accepted", hopefully it can clear things a little bit for other people who wish to understand this topic in detail. :)

Comment: You can figure out where .text is by looking at a gcc or as you have linked binary, then you can google the linux arm64 system calls and find the exit or equivalent and call that directly.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a bare minimum example.

Run it with:

```
gcc -c thisfile.S && ld thisfile.o && ./a.out
```

Source code:

```
    #include <sys/syscall.h>
    .global _start
_start:
    movq $SYS_write, %rax
    movq $1,         %rdi
    movq $st,        %rsi
    movq $(ed - st), %rdx
    syscall

    movq $SYS_exit,  %rax
    movq $1,         %rdi
    syscall
st:
    .ascii "\033[01;31mHello, OS World\033[0m\n"
ed:
```

Comment: This is for x86-64 Linux, not [arm].  And why do you want it to exit with an error status (non-zero)?  The normal way is `xor %edi, %edi` to set RDI to zero.  (And `SYS_exit` only takes a 32-bit arg anyway, so even without implicit zero-extension to 64-bit for writing a 32-bit register, zeroing EDI is the semantically correct thing to do.  Same for EDI for the file-descriptor arg to `write` being an `int`.  This is very un-optimized for code-size, using 64-bit operand-size everywhere unnecessarily).   Also, ANSI color(?) escape sequences in the string aren't exactly minimal.